# UIScrollview scrolls to top when paging is Enabled

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, paging

I have the **UIScrollView** with **pagingEnabled** set to **YES**, and programmatically scroll its content offset to a particular point where the user taps using the following code:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(x, y) animated: NO];
```

It scrolls successfully to this point (x,y), but now if I do a single tap ,its content scrolls up to top. 
When paging is disabled , it does not scroll to top but I need paging to be enabled.
Does any one know how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

check the class of the `otherGestureRecognizer` if it's a tap return NO, else return YES.